How to use Azure APIM to select subfield from a reponse inside an array
I have the following structure sent by an APIM service:
{
 "MainStruct": [
    {
    "F1": "",
    "F2": "",
    "StructA" : {
        "Results": [
        {
            "A1": "a1value",
            "A2": "a2value"
        }
        ]
    },
    "StructB" : {
        "Results": [
        {
            "B1": "b1value",
            "B2": "b2value"
        }
        ]
    }
    }   
 ]
}

(Unfortunately I cannot change the returned structure: "MainStruct" is an array and the values I need are inside another "Results" array, although threr is no need for that. I didn't set the structure. I can only query it)
How can I use $select for subfields that are inside an array? For instance: how can I use $select to get "B2", but not "B1", from StructB? (The actual response is much more complicated that that: inside "Results" for "StructB", there are actually hundreds of "B" fields, but I only need 4 of them. That's the reason for my question. If the overhead was only "B1", I could live with that).
Thanks in advance.
I tried using dot notation and "[*]" to access fields inside other fields and to referto array, but got errors as reponse.
